# Dynamically configure SqlQueryAttribute in BLToolkit?

Tags: sql, dynamic, bltoolkit

Does BLToolkit provide a facility similar to NHibernate's HQL; that is, allowing one to use dynamic SQL? I found this link in the BLToolkit documentation (http://bltoolkit.net/Doc.DACustomSqlQuery1.ashx?HL=sqlqueryattribute) that shows how to provide a number of different queries via a derived class of SqlQueryAttribute, but the SQL still is hard coded. I realize that tools such as BLToolkit were not designed for dynamic queries, but we're trying to standardize on a single data-access layer. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer was more evident than I thought: BL Toolkit exposes ExecuteXXX methods (Reader, DataSet, List) that couldn't make it more simple.